# prevent send cookie to wordpress in subroute

Tags: wordpress, security, cookies, blogs

I have a two websites.One is with `django` and onother on is `wordpress`.
I've configured `wordpress` on a url.For example `xyz.com/blog`.I handle my `django` sessions in cookie.
Now I worry about security of my `cookie`.What if some security issue become in `wordpress` and the attacker steal my cookies from `wordpress` blog?

Can I prevent sending cookies for my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies will be sent by the browser as long as the domain and the path matches. If you set path to "PathA" cookies will only be sent on requests to /PathA, but not to /PathB or /PathC. But you can't set it to send to all paths except PathA which seems to be what you want. If you only work with two paths such as /blog and /app you can set cookie path to /app and they should never go be included in requests to /blog.